# spring data cassandra upgrading spring boot 2.3.0 getting driver connection timeout exception

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Unexpected error while refreshing schema during initialization, keeping previous version (CompletionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.columns' timed out after PT2S)

Comment: If you are using DataStax then initiate command like `cqlsh --request-timeout=3600` or you can do cd ~/ and edit cqlshrc with your editor and modify client_timeout to a larger value. Let's give it a try and let me know if it does not work. Thanks